# Defining subfamilies for a font

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I wish to import from files a font family, which comes in extra light, light, regular, medium, bold and black. Instead of defining several different font names and choosing them as I need, it would be great if I could somehow define a single family and then attribute when I used different weights. Is this possible? I am using xelatex with fontspec. Is there an alternative to fontspec that offers an easy solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The manual of `fontspec` mentions the key `FontFace`. So let's assume your font are

```
BestFont-ExtraLight.otf
BestFont-ExtraLightItalic.otf
BestFont-Light.otf
BestFont-LightItalic.otf
BestFont-Regular.otf
BestFont-Italic.otf
BestFont-Medium.otf
BestFont-MediumItalic.otf
BestFont-Bold.otf
BestFont-BoldItalic.otf
BestFont-Black.otf
BestFont-BlackItalic.otf
```

Then you should be able to provide the font definition as

```
\setmainfont{BestFont}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  FontFace={xl}{n}{*-ExtraLight},
  FontFace={xl}{it}{*-ExtraLightItalic},
  FontFace={l}{n}{*-Light},
  FontFace={l}{it}{*-LightItalic},
  FontFace={mb}{n}{*-Medium},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{*-MediumItalic},
  FontFace={k}{n}{*-Black},
  FontFace={k}{it}{*-BlackItalic},
]
```

A real world example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Raleway}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Regular-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-Bold-Italic,
  FontFace={xl}{n}{*-ExtraLight},
  FontFace={xl}{it}{*-ExtraLight-Italic},
  FontFace={l}{n}{*-Light},
  FontFace={l}{it}{*-Light-Italic},
  FontFace={mb}{n}{*-Medium},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{*-Medium-Italic},
  FontFace={k}{n}{*-Black},
  FontFace={k}{it}{*-Black-Italic},
]

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\test}[2]{%
  #1: {\fontseries{#2}\selectfont This is upright. \itshape This is italic}\par
}

\test{ExtraLight}{xl}
\test{Light}{l}
\test{Regular}{m}
\test{Medium}{mb}
\test{Bold}{bx}
\test{Black}{k}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now you can also define font switching commands by yourself:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\xlseries{\fontseries{xl}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textxl}{\xlseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\lseries{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textl}{\lseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\mbseries{\fontseries{mb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmb}{\mbseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand\kseries{\fontseries{k}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textk}{\kseries}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! Will the commands `\textmd` and `\textlf` also automatically work after this?

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta No, you have to  define themi

Comment: So, in other words, there is no way to import a font from local files that would make the latex font weight commands to work out of the box beyond medium and bold?

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta There are so many variations, especially in font weight naming, that attempting to cover them is hopeless.

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta I added a model for font switching command definitions. For instance, `\textxl{foo}` will print in ExtraLight.

Comment: You have answered all my queries completely. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta You're very welcome!