# How can one semi-bold a small group of "normal text" words?

Tags: fonts

Bold often appears too drastic.
I would like to grade the weight of some fonts locally within the text, so that they stand out, but do not overwhelm.

Comment: You  first need a font that has semi-bold weight. Would you like to do that with `pdflatex` or with `xe/lualatex`?

Comment: If you’re using `fontspec`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264275/7883

Comment: I would prefer to use pdflatex.

Comment: You could use the package `pdfrender`. \textpdfrender{TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.1pt}{enter your text here}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This version displays Linux Libertine and Computer Modern Bright, two fonts that come in semibold weight.  These are just examples; the same approach should work for other fonts.  It adds `\sbseries` and `\textsb` commands corresponding to the standard LaTeX font selection commands.

#### Updated MWE for 2022

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[
              FontFace = {sb}{n}{* Semibold},
              FontFace = {sb}{it}{* Semibold Italic},
              BoldFont = {* Bold},
              BoldItalicFont = {* Bold Italic},
            ]
\setsansfont{CMU Bright}[
              FontFace = {sb}{n}{* SemiBold},
              FontFace = {sb}{it}{* SemiBold Oblique},
            ]

\else
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{cmbright}
%% Load without Biolinum, or it will replace CM Bright,
%% and without sb, or it will replace bold:
\usepackage[libertine]{libertine}

\fi         % \iftutex

% Suggested by David Carlisle:
\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
% Suggested by Clea F. Rees:
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\begin{document}

\framebox[10cm][s]{
\rmfamily \makebox[2.5cm][c]{Normal} \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\mdseries Medium} \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\sbseries Semibold} \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\bfseries Bold} \normalfont
} \par
\framebox[10cm][s]{
\makebox[2.5cm][c]{\textsf{Normal}} \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\textsf{\textmd{Medium}}}\makebox[2.5cm][c]{\textsf{\textsb{Semibold}}} \makebox[2.5cm][c]{\textsf{\textbf{Bold}}}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertine + CM Bright font sample]

Comment: `\textsb{something}` will change the font indefinitely and not just the weight of `something`. With XeLaTeX, this sends compilation into an infinite loop which I can only break by `kill`ing it. Is there any particular reason not to use the `libertine` package stuff given that it has configuration for `fontspec`? You want a `\DeclareTextFont...` for the `\text...` commands which should be defined in terms of the relevant font switch.

Comment: Also `utf8x` is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  It works in PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX now.  (The OP specifically asked for PDFLaTeX code.)  The main reason I didn’t just use the package is that I wanted to demonstrate how to do it for an arbitrary font.

Comment: And, OK, I changed `utf8x` to `utf8`.

Comment: You should use `\DeclareTextFontCommand...`. Take a look at the code of `nfssext-cfr.sty` for examples of how to do this. Or `font-axes.sty`. Or the original `nfssext.sty` (but this is in the documentation of the Font Installation Guide). But, in general, you ***cannot show how to do it for arbitrary fonts because it cannot be done for arbitrary fonts***. More precisely, to do this, you would have to take the user through all the required steps and that means reading `.fd` files (if available) etc. It is just misleading to suggest otherwise.

Comment: I took your advice and re-wrote to use \DeclareTextFontCommand.  Thanks!  To rephrase slightly, I was trying to show how to do it even if there’s no package that does it for you.  (Someone has to write the package!)

Comment: Again, cfr, thanks for the suggestions.  You improved my answer a lot.

Comment: Yes. This is true ;). I found The Font Installation Guide extremely helpful in this respect. (`nfssext-cfr` just extends the coverage to e.g. additional shapes/weights beyond those covered by `nfssext`.) Although it doesn't cover Xe/LuaLaTeX, the approach to NFSS is still useful, I think.

Comment: Note that your code will fail if the switch to semi-bold is unsuccessful. The best way to do this is to fall-back to e.g. `\bfseries` in that case. `\DeclareOldFontCommand` is not intended to be used in this way, I don't think.

Comment: I think any of the TeX engines will throw up an error message if the `-sc` font does not exist?  But yes, falling back to bold is a good workaround.

Comment: Normally, switching to a font shape/series which is not supported does not produce a compilation error. Depending on how things are set up, either the font is silently substituted or the font is substituted and a warning issued. For example `\scshape` doesn't produce an error if a font doesn't have small caps. If I load `nfssext-cfr` and say `\sbweight`, I won't get an error if the font doesn't have an `sb` series. (The idea is that `nfssext-cfr` provides generic extensions which are not specific to particular fonts - no font supports all the possibilities provided there.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28777/discussion-between-cfr-and-lorehead).

Answer (score 2):

By default, the New Font Selection Scheme (NFSS) for LaTeX supports a limited range of weights and shapes. Essentially, weight-wise, only bold extended and medium are supported by default. However, many fonts packaged for (pdf)LaTeX support extensions to the scheme.

The only thing to bear in mind here is that extensions, unlike the core LaTeX NFSS, are not uniform. The commands needed to access additional weights and shapes vary from font package to font package. While groups of font packages may share a common interface, there is no interface common to all such packages.

The trick here is to ***read the manuals of font packages*** to see which shapes, weights and swishy bits they support and what commands they provide to access these extensions to LaTeX's font selection scheme.

Here are a few examples of such packages. Since you expressed a preference for pdfTeX as an engine, I concentrate on options available here. Further information and options can be found in the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

While it is occasionally possible to access font features only by creating your own extensions to the NFSS, this should be a last resort: always check the packages for support in the first instance as this is (1) easier (2) more portable and (3) less error-prone.

## Libertine

The `libertine` package supports semi-bold out-of-the-box for all engines. If Xe/LuaLaTeX is used, it will configure opentype versions by default; otherwise, it will use type1.

This example uses pdfLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\bfseries\kant[2]
\libertineSB\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertine semi-bold]

## VenturisADF

Here are some examples of VenturisADF serif, titling and sans in various weights:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{venturis}
\begin{document}
Medium serif

{\bfseries Bold serif}

\texttl{\tistyle A demi-bold titling font}

{\sffamily\dbweight Demi-bold sans

\mdseries Regular sans

\lgweight Light sans

\bfseries Bold sans
}

\end{document}
```

[image: VenturisADF]

## ElectrumADF

Similarly, ElectrumADF features several weights:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{electrum}
\begin{document}

\textlg{From Light} through regular \textsb{and semibold} \textbf{to bold.}

\end{document}
```

[image: ElectrumADF]

Comment: You list the advantages of your approach over mine, and I don’t want to argue about which is better, but here are a few drawbacks.  First, your Libertine example does not do what the OP wanted, which was to be able to *switch between semibold and bold in the same document*.  The package maintainer only supplied a way to replace bold with semibold.  Second, most OpenType fonts don’t have LaTeX packages.  Third, what happens if someone using your approach wants to change fonts?  There‘s a reason every font package doesn’t have its own, incompatible boldface command.

Comment: While my solution does not work out of the box for literally every font family out there, it does work for every font family with a `sb` series, and every OpenType family with a Semibold font.  If you’re going to have to look stuff up and change some of the commands whenever you change fonts anyway, better one line in the preamble than a dozen in the body of your document. That said, I think our approaches are complementary.  I would personally recommend that people use semantic markup rather than put dependencies to a specific font in the body of their document.

Comment: @Lorehead (1) The document uses semi-bold and bold Libertine (and supports maths). (2) Most opentype fonts don't have packages but they cannot be used with pdfTeX anyway. Without at least basic support, you can't use a font in (pdf)TeX. (3) This is a limitation of the current system and quite unsatisfactory. But not using provided package support typically loses you a good deal. For example, `venturis` is set up so that you can use swash characters and various styles of figures, as well as different weights and shapes. And a one-size-fits-all-approach is, sadly, unlikely to give good results.

Comment: @Lorehead The claim about `libertine`'s package maintainer is just false: look at the documentation and/or take a look at the package code and/or take a look at my example.

Comment: Pardon; `libertine` does provide \LibertineSB.  You’re correct about that.  Here’s the thing.  Let’s say you switch from Libertine to another font.  Maybe it’s your publisher’s house style.  *You have to change your file either way.*  With my solution, you change one line in the preamble to load a new font, and it works.  With your solution, your documents fail to compile until you figure out that `{\LibertineSB\Kant}` should now be `\textsb{\Kant}` or `{\sffamily\dbweight\selectfont \Kant}`, and change every instance of them over.  Without, of course, introducing any errors.

Comment: @Lorehead Well, `\dbweight` is capturing a different font series anyway.

Comment: Thanks to Lorehead and cfr for such precise and detailed answers.