# Can any of fontenc, inputenx, txfonts, mathptmx, newunicodechar support semi-bold?

Tags: fonts

My amsbook document using the font packages fontenc, inputenx, txfonts, mathptmx, newunicodechar is nearly complete.
/
I don't want to introduce any more fonts at this stage.
Can I achieve semi-bold on **localized** normal text with this setup, please?

Comment: To use `semi-bold` fonts, you need… a font that does have a semi-bold  version and you have to declare it to LaTeX. I don't think TeX Gyre Termes that is used by default has a semi-bold version.

Comment: How is this different from the [question you asked](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264588/how-can-one-semi-bold-a-small-group-of-normal-text-words) just a few days ago?

Comment: Although the answer given was absolutely correct, I personally, could not sensibly integrate the code into my "nearly complete" document.

Comment: The answer given to my second question was simple to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `txfonts` and `mathptmx` don't have semibold fonts. But many other fonts do. One example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Regular bold} and {\libertineSB{localized semibold}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: The semibold is of the same height as the bold type (or if you have super vision, it's actually ever so slightly *taller* for the character `b`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\the\fontcharht\font`b}

{\libertineSB{\the\fontcharht\font`b}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: libertine works, but is it partly because it is inherently smaller?

Comment: @keith77777 i don't understand your question. It works because the font has a semibold version.

Comment: not a big issue, but it is shorter in height.

Comment: @keith77777 No it's not. It's just an optional illusion. I'll add proof in a sec.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it is an optical illusion.

Comment: Your answer is good.

Comment: I’m sure the OP finished his document years ago, but worth noting that `newtx` supports a `libertine` package option. In a modern toolchain, you can use `libertinus-otf`, or the Libertinus Math in `unicode-math` with either Linux Libertine or Libertinus Serif Semibold.

Answer (score 2):

First you need a font, which provides semi-bold. Because of `mathptmx` I assume, you want to have a semi-bold variant of Times? Usually, Times only comes with regular, bold, italics and bold italics.

A poor man's version can be created with package `pdfrender`. The glyphs of the outline font are additionally drawn with a configurable line width to get the impression of a semi-bold font.

However, the details are not so good as when a real semi-bold font is used. For example, the left stem of the `N` is even thicker than the bold version. Also the widths of the glyphs do not change.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\pmsb}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \pdfrender{
      TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
      LineWidth=.17pt,
    }%
    #1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\pmsb{\lipsum[2]}
\textbf{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]