# Softening the Bold

Tags: color, bold, lettrine

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\oddsidemargin 17pt \evensidemargin 18pt \topmargin 35pt \headheight 25pt \textheight 8.5in \textwidth 5.75in \headsep 40pt \marginparwidth 35pt
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{color}
%\definecolor{olivegreen}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.40}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initfamily{}}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{.47}

\begin{document} 
\vspace*{35pt}
\Large

\lettrine{\color{blue}{A}}{\color{blue}dvertising is the art} of convincing people to spend money they don't have for something they don't need. ---\textit{Will Rogers}

\vskip 35pt

\lettrine{\color{blue}{A}}{\textbf{\color{blue}advertising is the art}} of convincing people to spend money they don't have for something they don't need. \textit{---Will Rogers}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: In the first quote, I would like to darken the blue letters following the lettrine. However, the manner in which it is done in the second case seems a bit too harsh. How may I adjust the boldness of the blue text to something in between the two given shades of blue? Is there a way to specify this globally, in the event of many quotes?

Thank you.

Comment: It’s not the color that needs adjustment; the effect you seek would require a semibold font.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but would it not also be profitable to convince people to spend money they _do_ have?

Comment: I guess that basically you need something along the lines of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27843/82917

Comment: @Thérèse Would you elaborate a bit on what is meant by "a semibold font"? Thank you.

Comment: @Marijn Yes; but I recall that Will Rogers was a satirist during the Great Depression in the U.S in which some people lost everything beginning in 1929. I interpret his quip as a heavy-handed condemnation of advertisers in the U.S.

Comment: You can see examples in TeX Live: Libertinus, kpfonts-otf, Coelacanth, etc., all have a semibold weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [comment on a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264588/how-can-one-semi-bold-a-small-group-of-normal-text-words) mentions that you can use `\textpdfrender` from the `pdfrender` package with a specific linewidth. Typographically this is maybe not the cleanest but it may be an option if you can't find a font that has SemiBold defined.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\oddsidemargin 17pt \evensidemargin 18pt \topmargin 35pt \headheight 25pt \textheight 8.5in \textwidth 5.75in \headsep 40pt \marginparwidth 35pt
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{color}
%\definecolor{olivegreen}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.40}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initfamily{}}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{.47}

\begin{document} 
\vspace*{35pt}
\Large

\lettrine{\color{blue}{A}}{\color{blue}dvertising is the art} of convincing people to spend money they don't have for something they don't need. ---\textit{Will Rogers}

\vskip 35pt

\lettrine{\color{blue}{A}}{\color{blue}\textpdfrender{TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.1pt}{dvertising is the art}} of convincing people to spend money they don't have for something they don't need. ---\textit{Will Rogers}

\vskip 35pt

\lettrine{\color{blue}{A}}{\textbf{\color{blue}advertising is the art}} of convincing people to spend money they don't have for something they don't need. \textit{---Will Rogers}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. It seems that there is a predetermined level of "unboldness" that one can achieve with `\textpdfrender{TextRenderingMode=2,LineWidth=0.1pt}`, for when I  use, say, `LineWidth=0.0pt`, the shading does not revert back to the original,  but more closely resembles the bold in the second output of the original code.