# How many fonts can be used within one project/file?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

A theoretical question: I came across an interesting mono-spaced font called VictorMono.
It comes in seven weights and three styles ( Roman, Italian and Oblique). This gives us 21 different varieties of the same font. Now, if I am using XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX and `fontspec` package, can I make use of all available 21 varieties of this font within 1 project/file? How can this be done?
I have used custom fonts before, for example:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[
BoldFont=latinb.ttf,
ItalicFont=latini.ttf,
BoldItalicFont=latinbi.ttf,
BoldSlantedFont=latinbo.ttf
]{latin.ttf}
```

but I had only 4 font files in this example.

Comment: IIRC, DVI uses a one byte font selector, which means a 256 font limit.  Note that several of these are tied up in math fonts.

Comment: Classic TeX also has a limit of 16 math families, reflected in the syntax of some plain TeX primitives. However, XeTeX uses XDV and I believe LuaTeX can ignore limits set by DVI if compiling to PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an unlimited number of font weights and series with the  `FontFace=` option.  You can see the `nfssext-cfr` package for some semi-standardized examples of additional shapes and series, but you can define completely arbitrary ones if you truly wanted to.

[Here is one example.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264265/defining-subfamilies-for-a-font/264275#264275)

Comment: I get a practical physical threshold of about 60-80 font families before resources (I presume memory) runs out, on my machine. Somewhat even less, it appears to me, if the font files are CJK fonts and 10 MB each. But otherwise, no limit.